# What does monotonically convergent mean in this example.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(x\in X)$$Where $f_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ for $n=1,2,3...$ Let $g_N=f_1+...+f_N$. Then the sequence $\{g_N\}$ converges monotonically to $f$.

What I do not understand is as to why it is monotonic. What does the phrase "converges monotonically to" mean here?

Comment: For each $x$, the sequence $(g_n(x))$ increases to $f(x)$.

Comment: Because the range of the functions are positive numbers (with $+\infty$ included). The partial sums never decrease, even when the value $+\infty$ was reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence of functions $\{g_N\}$ is increasing if for every $x$, $\{g_N(x)\}$ is an increasing sequence of numbers. Note that this is completely different from saying that the functions $g_N$ are increasing functions; neither of two properties implies the other. One property describes what happens when $N$ changes, the other describes what happens when $x$ changes.

A typical example: if $f_1,f_2,\dots$ is any sequence of nonnegative functions, then the sequence of partial sums $g_1=f_1$, $f_2=f_1+f_2$, ... is increasing.

Similarly, a sequence of functions $\{g_N\}$ is decreasing if for every $x$, $\{g_N(x)\}$ is an decreasing sequence of numbers. Finally, $\{g_N\}$ is monotone if it's either increasing or decreasing.

A statement that some sequence "converges monotonically" is a combination of two statements:

1. the sequence converges
2. the sequence is monotone